# Trying to create a shortcode with $atts. I'm learning

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I'm having trouble getting my shortcode to output the proper code with this shortcode I made for WordPress. I'm trying to get my short code [onecol] to accept an attribute with one of two values "first" and "last", and if no attribute is entered then I want it to use a default value. Then I want it to render some output similar to this:

```
<div class="onecol first clearfix">Hello World</div>
```

And I want the shortcode to look like this:

```
[onecol col="first"]Hello World[/onecol]
```

This is the code I have so far:

```
function one_col( $atts, $content = null ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'class' => 'col'
    ), $atts ) );

    $depth = 0;
    $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);

    return "\n$indent<div class=\"onecol " . esc_attr__($class) . " clearfix\">\n" . $content . "$indent</div>\n";
}

add_shortcode( 'onecol', 'one_col' );
```

So far this outputs:

```
<div class="onecol col clearfix>Hello World</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't waste time indenting HTML. Whitespace is meaningless

Answer (score 0):

You simply have your attribute name wrong. Try this...

```
add_shortcode('onecol', function($atts, $content = null) {
    extract(shortcode_atts([
        'col' => 'first' // this is your default "col" attribute value
    ], $atts));

    return sprintf('<div class="onecol %s clearfix">%s</div>',
        htmlspecialchars($col), do_shortcode($content));
});
```

This uses PHP 5.4 array syntax and a PHP 5.3 closure. Substitute for whatever you need to make it work if you're stuck on an older version.